# zip files to aws s3 eroor

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-codepipeline

in simple, I run the command in jenkins.
Compress-Archive -Path .\dist* -DestinationPath .\destfolderapp.zip -Force
after this I upload it to s3 with cli. When I extract(un zipping and copying to another bucket) with help of aws-pipeline all folders converted to filenames.
App
|+folder1
|+file1
|+file2 this folder structure in original zip. after copying and extraction in final bucket. it appears like App\folder1\file1. Not showing directories in final bucket.? can someone will help me?
Thanks in advance